# What is the purpose of the thick blue line in this schematic?

Tags: schematics, wire, computers

On this schematic for a Z80 computer, there appears to be a thick blue wire connecting some components together. What is it? Googling yields no results: [here is the schematic](http://searle.hostei.com/grant/cpm/CPMSchematic1.2.gif)

[image]

Comment: Where is the schematic?

Comment: Without actually seeing through your eyes at the schematic that only you have, I can only guess that it may be a bus.

Comment: Sorry, Forgot the link!

Comment: Seeing your edited link, @Majenko is correct - it's a bus. It's a good alternative to running individual wires between components (leading to a very complex diagram) or just labelling them (leading to schematic wide hunting for the other corresponding label).

Comment: So if it was built on a breadboard, I could just use individual wires?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The thick bus line is simply a way to make the schematics cleaner.  Kind of like using ground symbols instead of drawing connecting lines for all the ground points...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are buses.  The address, and the data bus.

They are basically a way of drawing lots of nets without having to draw each individual one.  The label by the nets that connect to it define what connections are inside the bus.